# Multiple SQL Server installations on ONE server?

Tags: sql-server

Across our business we have several low-volume SQL Server installations; added as we have developed/acquired new products for the business. Each one is located on a virtual server and for argument sake let's say there are 5 such servers and each has been allocated 8Gb RAM and 4 CPUs ... in my mind, I think that it would make more sense to collated these onto ONE server, beefed up with memory/CPU.

I see the PROs of this being that it makes it easier to keep track of the servers, to maintain them, upgrade (when required), assigning permissions would be easier and the performance may be increased (by adding additional RAM/CPU). Presumably, we could also have the server replicated/load balanced to give additional resilience.

Am I correct to think that?

What would be the considerations AGAINST doing this?

Comment: if this one server is down - all applications are down too (for example during upgrade)

Comment: Performance will not be increased if the SQL Servers are separate instances -- there is no code in SQL Server that allows it to effectively cooperate with different instances of itself any more than it would with other applications on the same machine. Having only one virtual server as opposed to many might make better use of the underlying hardware, but that's by no means a given.

Comment: Unless each instance has different settings (like collation) I'll merge them into a single instance with more memory/CPU.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I was thinking of the performance being improved by adding extra RAM/CPU; in my example we have 40GB RAM and 20 CPU spread across 5 servers ... after collating to one server, we could assign all of that one the server.

Comment: Yes, but unless you consolidate all those instances into one, you have to either explicitly manage the settings so the SQL Servers don't tread on each other's toes (think max RAM) or else hope that the instances which need resources will gobble them up without the rest being too starved for them. This is generally a headache you don't need; per @McNets, if possible you want to see if you can just have the different databases on a single instance on the beefiest server possible.

Comment: McNets/Jeroen - I like the sound of that; shouldn't be a problem having them all in one instance; I'm not aware of any particular settings that would prevent that happening. From what I am reading (on other sites, too) this would be a positive move; obviously, noting the comment from Ilya that if one server is down, everything is down.

Comment: Or you can let two instances running, then you could move db's just in case one of them have a problem.

Comment: Do not underestimate the possible damage from not being redundant, by the way -- in your current setup, a runaway application can peg at most one virtual server; in the new setup, it could eat up all the resources you have. A collection of VMs can run on physically redundant hardware; on one beefy server, a single damaged RAID controller is enough to stop the whole show. And so on -- you can quantify these risks and take steps to mitigate them, and you should. SQL/Windows clustering is an option, but it has more moving parts and is harder to administer than VM redundancy.

Answer (score 6):

To assist with your research, this is often called "Instance Stacking" when discussing installing multiple instances of SQL Server on the same box.

You can read about some of the pros and cons here: [Should I Install Multiple Instances of SQL Server?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/12/install-multiple-instances-sql-server/)

The biggest downsides would be maintenance / availability, which [Iłya Bursov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864275/i%C5%82ya-bursov) mentioned in the comments:

> if this one server is down - all applications are down too (for example during upgrade)

Over time, it can become very difficult to schedule downtime as more apps are added to the machine.

The other tough one is performance.  Making sure that the max and min memory settings for each instance or configured to keep from oversubscribing the box.  Going all rocket surgeon with affinity masking to make sure CPU is distributed (or not doing that and letting one instance trash the server).

This also makes it tough to understand wait stats and other performance metrics, since they are usually reported at the instance level.  You'll need to aggregate them somewhere, or correlate the stats between the different instances.

---

You can weigh these challenges against the licensing savings / convenience of only having one Windows box.  It sounds like perhaps these applications are not super resource intensive, or not 24/7 or business critical, in which case you could be in for a quick win in terms of licensing and manageability!  But it's good to see all sides in order to make an informed choice.